# cannot properly view cfm files with ColdFusion builder

Tags: file, view, coldfusion, adobe

I am just starting out with ColdFusion, and have installed it along with ColdFusion builder 2. I've created a project in cf builder 2 which was initialized with the cfdocs and CFIDE folders. However, when I try to view the cfm files that are contained within those folders (such as Application.cfm or homepage.cfm) using the editor, most of the time I get replacement/invalid characters (�, []) scattered throughout the text. Is there a reason for it/way to view the files normally? It seems files that come with ColdFusion builder/ColdFusion/adobe stuff should be rendered properly.

Comment: strangely enough I tried opening some of the core files with notepad and wordpad and they both also printed loads of invalid chars. I guess it has to do with the CFIDE and cfdocs files themselves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are compiled if you're talking about .cfm/.cfc in /CFIDE. Adobe is not sharing the source with us on those. :)

You can compile your own cfm's using [cfcompile](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7fd0.html)

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Wasn't sure that would be the case since half of the code could be traced to something on the corresponding pages by looking at it. Didn't realize compiled cfms/cfcs had the same extension as regular ones. Boy do I have a lot learn about all this. Could you suggest any good free tutorials on coldfusion (something to explain the markup language/project structure/what corresponds to what within CFBuilder), by any chance

Comment: Free tutorials on ColdFusion?  Hmm... I found Adobe's Developing ColdFusion 9 Applications at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/index.html pretty good.  It's not that hard, just ask here when you have any Q.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't seem to difficult once you see what you're doing wrong, but there seems to be less of a community around it as around open source platforms/language. It's probably the product of me being a noob though.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you set different projects to have the same home (C:\Jrun4 seems to be the default), will there be any conflicts, or will they just be represented as different concurrent subdirectories on the same server

Comment: Maybe you can view some of the presentations on ColdFusion Builder here: http://www.carehart.org/ugtv/index.cfm

Comment: To get started, just make a sub dir, and add a new Application.cfc with this.name = something unique in it, and there, you got yourself a new ColdFusion application with own Application scope.

Comment: Thanks. I was given three .cfm files that ideally I should be able to deploy, but when I try pasting them into a sub directory and navigating the browser to the corresponding location I am given the error occurred while processing request window, though one of them renders the page halfway. Is there some build, initialization, cfc vs cfm issues I'm overlooking by any chance? I'd ask the resident cf expert but he's on vacation so I have to power through it all via trial and error

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for CF based tutorials, check out http://www.easycfm.com/. It has tutorials for all levels of CF developers.

hth,
larry

Comment: Wow that's far more helpful than anything I've been able to find so far. Thanks.